# Dependent api call in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, api, react-functional-component

So I have a functional component that makes an API call to get a "player" json object. In that fetched "player" object, I have a nested "team" json object that contains an id that I need to use in a separate API call. Since the nature of API calls are asynchronous, how can I guarantee the second API call will work.

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState({});

async function fetchPlayer() {
    const res = await fetch(baseUrl + "/Players/" + player_id);
    res
        .json()
        .then(res => setPlayer(res));
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchPlayer();
}, []);


const { 
    firstname = " ", 
    lastname = " ",
    team
} = player;

const {
    name = " ",
    team_id = 0
} = team || {};


// what I want to do. Team_id isn't set however...

const [thing, SetThing] = useState({});

async function fetchThing() {
        const res = await fetch(baseUrl + "/Thing/" + team_id);
        res
            .json()
            .then(res => setThing(res));
    }
```

Basically I'm already able to get the team json object and it's team_id but I'm not sure how I can implement another API call that depends on team id.

I've tried just adding another async function to house the second API call but inside that call, team_id has not yet been set by the first API call. Any ideas would be great, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that you could add value to the second argument to "listen" to. Changes to that value will call that useEffect it's tied to. For example I added this:

```
const [thing, setThing] = useState({});

async function fetchThing() {
        const res = await fetch(baseUrl + "/Thing/" + team_id);
        res
            .json()
            .then(res => setThing(res));
    }

useEffect(() => {
    fetchThing();
}, [team_id]);
```

So now the useEffect above will trigger when team_id changes. So it's guaranteed that team_id is set and then the useEffect calls the fetch with the new team_id that we were waiting for from the first API call.