# What is the best way of fetching dependent data from the API in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, restful-url

So, I have dependent data that I need to fetch from the REST API. The data A have some key information in data B, so it is necessary to make sure to fetch (and LOAD) data B before data A.

What is the best way of doing this in React?? I solved this problem with recursive function that accepts array of strings as API endpoints, and fire it one after another, but I wonder is this the proper way of sequential API call in React?

Comment: Check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491795/dependent-api-call-in-react-functional-component

Comment: Thanks @HarmandeepSinghKalsi. Solution in the link you sent is functional, and it IS the answer to my question, however, for my project, the recursive function that I already have is more reusable, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If Fetch(A) is going to be dependent on Fetch(B), then you can simply leverage async-await to do this sequentially.

```
async () => {
  const res = await fetch(URL_FOR_B); // get data B first
  const data = await res.json();

  const nextRes = await fetch(URL_FOR_A, { param: data.params });
  const nextData = await nextRes.json();

  console.log("Data at the end: ", nextData);
};
```

There are other approaches too: `then` with wrapped `Promise` but `await` is clean and sequentially readable.

Comment: This is a VERY good answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think, however, that my original solution with recursive function is more reusable. I can use it for any number of cases where I should send a sequence of N functions to be executed in order.